# Partial derivative of a Group Lasso

Tags: lasso, quadratic-form, convex, differential-equations

I am looking at the gradient descent method for group lasso questions. Here's what I am currently stuck at.

Given the quadratic form of the objective function:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^T V x - m^T x + \sum_{l=1}^g \|x_{G_l}\|_2
$$
where $x$ and $m$ are vectors and $V$ is the positive semidefinite matrix. The $x_{G_l}$ is just referring to the vector of the elements in group $G_l$. The objective function is assumed to be differentiable and convex, and the $\|X_{G_l}\|$ can be $=0$ and $\neq 0$.

I was able to find the partial derivative for the first two components of the objective function:
$$
f'(x) = Vx - m
$$

However, I became confused with doing partial differentiation for group lasso. I know if I have $\|x\|_2^2$, I can easily differentiate it to $2x$.

Can anyone give an insight on how I should proceed?

Comment: Is $x\mapsto \|x\|_2$ differentiable for all $x$?

Comment: @user551504 I have added another criterion for the group lasso.

Comment: The purpose of the group lasso is to induce sparsity, so $x \mapsto \|x\|_2$ is being used specifically because it is not differentiable at $x=0$. So what should we do? One way forward to use subgradient descent instead of gradient descent.

Comment: This is a good way to try at. I'll check about it and see what I can get. Thanks!

Comment: OK, do you know how to calculate the subgradient of $x \mapsto \|x\|_2$?

Comment: Apparently no, I am still new to optimization.

Comment: OK, the pdf here explains subgradients and gives your problem as an example http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/subgradients.pdf see page 8 in particular